# hive internal error with Amplab shark on spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, shark-sql

Please... Help needed.

I have followed steps to build spark and shark to query data from hdfs/cassandra. I have a cassandra cluster on hdfs and can successfully view database. But can not run a select statement

shark> select * from calls_flow limit 1;
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.cql.HiveCqlInputFormat)

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Environment: cassandra 2.0.8, spark-0.9.0, shark-0.9.0

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO about ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the cassandra jars and cassandra-hive driver/InputFormat jar are copied into the shark lib directory on all of your cluster machines.